Made to Make the Mouth Water
Brits may remember a TV-advertising jingle for a fruity confection (a collection of sweets in a rectangular tube), "Opal Fruits": "Opal Fruits, made to make your mouth water!"
Making one's mouth water, in Latin, would be?
Verb, "salivare" and feminine noun "saliva" are the only things I can think of. Therefore:

"ad salivam faciendam (poma) facta"--


"Made for the purpose of producing saliva,"

This English translation may not make it as an advertising jingle.
Is there a better way to express this jingle, in Latin?
Interesting to note that Oxford gives "saliva" as both "spittle" and a "distinctive flavour". Anyone who ate those fruity delights might well support that alternative translation--"Made to produce a distinctive flavour"--it's getting better already!

Factam is wrong, as the participle must agree with the implied noun, not anything in the gerundive phrase. So, fructus facti, fruges factae, poma facta.

@Kingshorsey: Thank you.

Trop., taste, flavor; longing, appetite (poet., and in post-Aug. prose):
    “Methymnaei Graia saliva meri,” Prop. 4 (5), 8, 38. cf.
    “suo cuique vino saliva,” Plin. 23, 1, 22, § 40
    “mercurialis,” for gain, Pers. 5, 112
    “turdarum,” id. 6, 24
    “Aetna tibi salivam movet,” makes your mouth water, Sen. Ep. 79, 7
    “quicquid (sc. vinum) ad salivam facit,” Petr. 48, 2.

@Antonio Silva: Thanks. Why not make this into an answer?
